# Forward slash not allowing linking within page

Tags: html, magento, hyperlink

I am working within Magento and added an anchor for a specific link. The link has to open a semi-link within a page as

```
www.mysite.com/category/about#semi-link
```

This brings me to the content which I want to open with the aforementioned link.

Now, when I put in the link within the link field (without forward slash) in Magento, it automatically adds in a forward slash. The problem is that when it adds a forward slash it, doesn't move to

Hence it becomes like this

```
 www.mysite.com/category/about#semi-link/
```

Is there any way I can bypass that?

Thanks.

Comment: please add your sample code in your answer

Answer (score 0):

some more details required are you trying it like

```
<a href="#semi-link">Your Link Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Yes. It all is working but with a URL like `www.mysite.com/category/about#semi-link` but I also want this page to work when a system accesses the page with a URL like this `www.mysite.com/category/about#semi-link/`. Probably page should be removing forward slash of the URL on page load through JQuery? Thanks

Comment: can you make a fiddle